# Show that $\max(2^{K-1}, P - 1) \leq \varphi(n) \leq n \leq P^K$

Tags: number-theory

> For any prime $p$ and $n, k_i \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, we have
>
> $$n = \prod_{i = 1}^m p_i^{k_i}.$$
>
> Let $K = \sum_{i = 1}^m k_i$ and $P = \max\{p_i : 1 \leq i \leq m\}$ and $\varphi(n)$ the Euler totient function. Show that
>
> $$\max(2^{K-1}, P - 1) \leq \varphi(n) \leq n \leq P^K.$$
>
> Deduce that
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi(n) = + \infty.$$

For the first bit, I have said that we can see that $\varphi(n) \leq n$ by defintion of $\varphi(n)$ (which I have already defined in an earlier part of the question. As $P$ is the max prime that can divide $n$ and as $K$ is the sum of all the $k$'s of these primes, we can see that $P^K$ will be $\geq n$.

I'm not stuck on how to prove the final bit, on the left hand side.

Also, for the deduce bit, I said that as we have seen that $\varphi(n) \leq n$, this says that as $n \to \infty$, we get that $\varphi(n) \to \infty \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} (\varphi(n) = + \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)$$.

$$\phi(n)\geq n\prod_{i=1}^m\frac{(p_i-1)}{p_i}\geq \prod_{i=1}^m (p_i-1)\geq P-1.$$

Think about a similar idea for showing the $2^{K-1}$ part. To show $\phi$ goes to infinity, you need to show that either $2^{K-1}$ or $P-1$ gets arbitrarely large. For example when $n$ is prime, you get $P=n$. In other cases, large numbers have large $k_i$ so then $K$ is big. Try to combine these ideas.